# Gunicorn error running same Django configuration and code for the last three years

Tags: python, django, gunicorn, supervisord

For the last three years below gunicorn configuration worked well:

```
[program:hys]
command= /usr/local/bin/gunicorn /var/www/h/o/u67098/public_html/project/apps/,/var/www/h/o/u67098/public_html/project/,/var/www/h/o/u67098/public_html/apps/,/var/www/h/o/u67098/public_html/ project.wsgi:application -b=0.0.0.0:8001 --workers=3 --timeout=90 --graceful-timeout=10 --log-level=INFO --log-file /var/www/h/o/u67098/public_html/logs/gun.log

directory = /var/www/h/o/u67098/public_html/project/
user = hys
autostart=true
autorestart=true

stdout_logfile = /var/www/h/o/u67098/public_html/logs/gunicorn_supervisor.log
stderr_logfile= /var/www/h/o/u67098/public_html/logs/gunicorn_err_supervisor.log
redirect_stderr = true ; Save stderr in the same log
environment=LANG=en_US.UTF-8,LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Since NY I am getting this error:

```
[2020-01-05 10:45:16 +0000] [20624] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
[2020-01-05 10:45:16 +0000] [20624] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8001 (20624)
[2020-01-05 10:45:16 +0000] [20624] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2020-01-05 10:45:16 +0000] [20629] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 20629
[2020-01-05 10:45:16 +0000] [20629] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn-19.7.1-py2.7.egg/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 578, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn-19.7.1-py2.7.egg/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn-19.7.1-py2.7.egg/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 135, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn-19.7.1-py2.7.egg/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn-19.7.1-py2.7.egg/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn-19.7.1-py2.7.egg/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn-19.7.1-py2.7.egg/gunicorn/util.py", line 352, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ImportError: Import by filename is not supported.
```

The code works, I can start the dev server in Django, no errors.
Gunicorn self seems to be working as well, it responds in the command line. I have no other project to test it, but I did reinstall it and the issue persists.

Django 1.11.2
Python 2.7.3
Gunicorn 19.7.1

Any ideas what is wrong here?

Comment: What are all the directories as the first argument to gunicorn?

Comment: That's for the PythonPath. I mean, enviroment variables, locations of apps mostly that need to be found by django.

Comment: Should that not be in an env var?

Comment: I'll try changing it. But as I am saying, it worked for three years. I remember this was the only way to make it work, it wouldn't start. It;s three years and no updates in between, I barely remember the details ... but this was the only way to make it work

Comment: Could you advise how to do that? I tried using environementFile and environemnt paramter, but it;s not added and django is not found.

Comment: Is this a supervisord conf file?

Comment: Yes. It truly is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `PYTHONPATH` in the `environment` setting of your config

```
environment=LANG=en_US.UTF-8,LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8,PYTHONPATH=/var/www/h/o/u67098/public_html/project/apps/:/var/www/h/o/u67098/public_html/project/:/var/www/h/o/u67098/public_html/apps/:/var/www/h/o/u67098/public_html/
```

Comment: supervisorctl reload      
error: <class 'socket.error'>, [Errno 2] No such file or directory: file: /usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py line: 224

Comment: Starting supervisor: Error: Format string 'LANG=en_US.UTF-8,LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8,PYTHONPATH=/var/www/h/o/u67098/public_html/project/apps/:/var/www/h/o/u67098/public_html/project/:/var/www/h/o/u67098/public_html/apps/:/var/www/h/o/u67098/public_html/:%(ENV_PYTHONPATH)s' for 'environment' contains names which cannot be expanded

Comment: Which version of supervisor are you using? You might get away with just removing `:%(ENV_PYTHONPATH)s` from the line

Comment: You are my hero, thank you. It worked, without :%(ENV_PYTHONPATH)s